# lobos.migrations not found in Maven-style project layout

Tags: maven, clojure, leiningen

I'm having trouble getting the [lobos](https://github.com/budu/lobos) database migrations library for Clojure to play with the maven-clojure-plugin and Maven-style project structure. Lobos looks for database migrations in the `lobos.migrations` namespace. If I layout the project Leiningen style:

```
src/
  lobos/
    migrations.clj
```

lobos correctly finds `lobos.migrations` at run time, when run via `lein`. However, if I lay out the project Maven-style:

```
src/
  main/
    clojure/
      lobos/
        migrations.clj
```

and use the `maven-clojure-plugin` to run the same tests, lobos no longer finds `lobos.migrations`. I thought this was an issue with the `clojure-maven-plugin`, but I have the same issue (lobos not finding `lobos.migrations`) if I run via leon, setting the source paths in `project.clj` appropriately:

```
:source-paths      ["src/main/clojure"]
```

If I move `lobos/` back under `src/` and add `src/` as a source path:

```
:source-paths      ["src" "src/main/clojure"]
```

then lobos correctly finds `lobos.migrations` again.

I would like to use a Maven-style project layout (and eventually the maven-clojure-plugin). How can I help lobos find `lobos.migrations`? Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lobos.migration/*src-directory*` variable indicates the source root for finding *source* for the `*migrations-namespace*`. If `lobos.migration/*reload-migrations*` is true (the default), then `lobos.migrations` looks for the migrations namespace in this source directory. The default is `src/`, so it needs to be rebound to `src/main/clojure` in order to use a Maven-style directory structure.

One other notable issue: when running from a JAR (i.e. not from source), you must disable reloading of the migrations namespace as well:

```
(binding [lobos.migration/*reload-migrations* false]
   ;; run migration
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the dynamic variable `lobos.migration/*migrations-namespace*`. This is documented here: https://github.com/budu/lobos#migrations.

Comment: @BarryWark What kind of an error did you get after rebinding?